# Set environment variable by reference in a function

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash function to init some environment variables.
I want to append a path to them unless it is already there.

I'd call it like

```
$ add_to_path /home/brucewayne MYENV
```

This is what I have so far.

```
# adds $1 to path $2 (e.g. add '/opt/blabla' to $PYTHONPATH)
add_to_path() {
    if [ -d "$1" ] && [[ ":${!2}:" != *":$1:"* ]]; then
        $2="$1:${!2}"
    fi
}
```

but when I run it, I get

```
./a.sh: line 6: MYENV=/home/brucewayne:/home/pal: No such file or directory
```

My guess is that `$2="$1:${!2}"` is not being interpreted as an assignment.
$2 should become MYENV and the value should be set to MYENV but, instead, it looks like I can't set the value by reference.
What would be a correct way of doing this in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `export` in your function:

```
add_to_path() {
    if [ -d "$1" ] && [[ ":${!2}:" != *":$1:"* ]]; then
       export $2="$1:${!2}"
    fi
}
```

Comment: damn it I had tried that but with a different right side and failed. thanks! it does work

Comment: You can make it a bit cleaner by using: [[ -d "$1" && ":${!2}:" != *":$1:"* ]] && export $2="$1:${!2}".  The if .. then .. fi construct would no longer be needed.